# is there any method to simply ignore some files in unity build?

Tags: unity, debugging, build-process

as im trying to build my new app on unity android specially when i want to use gradle, there is always some conflict with manifest or libraries and .....

for debug and problem exploration i need to ignore some folders to check for those bugs instead of need to move them somewhere else.

i just thought about git branching but it can cause lots of branches and maybe not efficient

Comment: there's currently an unresolved feedback entry for this https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/allow-tagging-folders-for-exclusion-in-builds so I've added a workaround for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the folders to one of the Unity's 'Special Folder Names' and they will be ignored:  If you're on Windows, setting the folders to 'Hidden' would probably be the easiest as it likely won't be picked up as a 'change' by version control.

> During the import process, Unity completely ignores the following
> files and folders in the Assets folder (or a sub-folder within it):
>
> - Hidden folders.
> - Files and folders which start with ‘.’.
> - Files and folders which end with ‘~’.
> - Files and folders named cvs.
> - Files with the extension .tmp.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html